# Exact place to register observer in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, model, observers

When using a separate class for a model observer, where exactly should I register the observer? The documentation says to call `User::observe(new UserObserver);` but I’m not sure where the best place to do this would be.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since an observer is just a collection of events you are listening to, I'd say place it where Laravel suggests you place individual events: on the `boot` method of the model itself.

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        User::observe(new UserObserver);
    }
}
```

Where to put the `UserObserver` class is a little more flexible and depends on how complex it will end up being.

### For simple observers

If you can bare having it load every time the app runs, create an `app/observers.php` file, then put this at the end of your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/observers.php';
```

Alternatively, you can use composer to autoload that one file, by appending your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            //...
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/observers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

### For more complex observers

If you plan to have many different observers, I'd say create your own namespace and let Laravel / Composer do the autoloading for you. In order to do that, create a folder like `app/MyNamespace/Observers`, then place each observer file inside of it (each named exactly like the class -- i.e. `UserObserver.php`).

Your `UserObserver.php` class should now look like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Observers;

class UserObserver
{
    public function saving($model)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And you'll have to declare the full class whenever you are using it:

```
User::observe(new MyNamespace\Observers\UserObserver);
```

Or:

```
use MyNamespace\Observers\UserObserver;

class User extends Eloquent
{    
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        User::observe(new UserObserver);
    }
}
```

Finally, edit your `composer.json` and add your namespace to follow PSR-0 autoloading:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            //...
        ],
        "psr-0": [
            "MyNamespace": "app/"
        ]
    }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` after editing `composer.json`.

Comment: You complex approach worked like a charm for me. Thanks!